# Is 'I was not-so-joking' correctly said?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing a text in which the first sentence is a joke about my aspirations.

> Since my mom didn’t let me be a rockstar[...]

But further on I say that I play guitar on my free time, so that the first sentence wasn't a complete joke, but just a little bit.

So I wrote this:

> [...]I am usually playing my guitars (**I was not-so-joking** about the
>   rockstar thing)[...]

I had read the "not-so-joking" construction in several books or articles (google search, of course).

So is it okay? If not, what would be the right way to express it?

Comment: It is possible to create those adjectives but they  have to modify a noun and not be used as a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to be understood, the **not-so-joking** adjectival agglomeration will achieve that. Even if it seems unfamiliar to a native-speaking reader, they will easily figure out what you mean.

Nevertheless, simplicity is usually your best default goal in writing. If you want to go that route, I'd suggest the following:

> I'm usually playing my guitars (I wasn't really joking about the rockstar thing).

But you can still use "not-so-joking" instead without causing confusion.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to construct a hyphenated word beginning with *not-so-*, it would sound most natural to end it with an adjective and treat the whole construction as an adjective, or to end it with an adverb and treat the whole construction as an adverb.

An example of an adjective construction:

> I picked up the **not-so-hot** plate.

An example of an adverb construction:

> I was **not-so-much** joking about the rockstar thing.

You could use an ambiguous or wishy-washy adverb, such as *not really*, *not exactly*, *sort of*, or *kind of*, in place of a constructed adverb.

> I was **not exactly** joking about the rockstar thing.
>
> I was **sort of** joking about the rockstar thing.

You could also use an adverb that clearly conveys the meaning you want in this sentence, such as *halfway* or *partially*. The *only* in front of it further emphasizes that you were not fully joking.

> I was **only halfway** joking about the rockstar thing.